# Error While Reading a text file with stream reader

Tags: c#, filestream

1) I'm trying to read a text file but it shows error Like

> *foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' because 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'*

Here is my **C#** code...

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\test1.txt"))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    //contents of foreach loop go here

                        foreach (var line in sr)
                        {
                            var items = line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
                            if (items.Length != 3)
                                continue;
                            var Name = items[0].ToString();
                            var Email = items[1].ToString();
                            var Pwd = items[2].ToString();
                            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values('" + Name + "','" + Email + "','" + Pwd + "')";
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                }
```

Comment: .ReadLine ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you even google it? I mean, just once!

Comment: Yes sir i'm working for solution since today morning not only once but so many time i've google it... Thank you sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what Alex.K comment say:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\test1.txt"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        var items = line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
        if (items.Length != 3)
            continue;
        var Name = items[0].ToString();
        var Email = items[1].ToString();
        var Pwd = items[2].ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values('" + Name + "','" + Email + "','" + Pwd + "')";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You don't need `foreach` inside peek check loop, just read a line.

Here is a typical use from MSDN, which is very clear of how to read lines:

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

### Edit

To avoid famous `SQL injection vulnerability`, deal with parameters using [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx):

```
// this is baaaaad
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values('" + Name + "','" + Email + "','" + Pwd + "')";

// will become
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values(@Name, @Email, @Pwd)";
cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
cmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = Email;
cmd.Parameters["@Pwd"].Value = Pwd;

// somewhere before, where you create command
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", type);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", type);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pwd", type);
```

Comment: Someone is waiting for sql injection comment i think you wants to say something like... Using parameters in your sql is much more secure. As this is written, you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Am i right sir...???

Comment: I was trying to be funny.. but then suddenly I become serious. =D And yes, if either of values can be entered by the user, you are in danger!

Comment: Sir i'm a begineer in this field but suddenly i also noticed you comment so i google it and gain your attention but sir i'm not knowing solution for this sql injection so please can you explain it by modifying my code sir...Thank you... :D

Answer (score 1):

This is going to work for this. Instead of `ForEach` Loop, use a `while` loop

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\test1.txt"))
 {
      while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
      {
       //contents of foreach loop go here

       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
       var items = line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
       if (items.Length != 3)
                    continue;
       var Name = items[0].ToString();
       var Email = items[1].ToString();
       var Pwd = items[2].ToString();
       cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values('" + Name + "','" + Email + "','" + Pwd + "')";
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


          }
  }
```

Comment: until your line returns null, this while loop will execute. If you want to break at any point, you can do it conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear.

You can only iterate over via `foreach` on elements that implements the `GetEnumerator` method, and `StreamReader` isn't.

There are plenty of excellent and good example for `StreamReader` just look one up.

Comment: Yeah got that foreach loop can be iterated on elements that implements GetEnumrator method but i'm asking for it's solution sir...

Answer (score 0):

you can use for in this type

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\test1.txt"))
{
}
```

Comment: Sir your foeach loop will also keep executing...number of data i my sample file is only 10 but stored in database is 100800